# Angular 7 & ngUpgrade: define global css just for Angular components

Tags: angularjs, angular, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a problem, I have an old, huge AngularJS project that uses Bootstrap 3 engine. Now, I started upgrading it to modern Angular 7 and I want to implement [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) library, which require Bootstrap 4. I want to make transition gradually - component by component.

Now, back to Bootstrap problem, it turns out that Bootstrap 4 has a lot of breaking changes and just switching to a new version broke everything.

Is there a way, to include Bootstrap 4 to all my Angular 7 components, but do it like Angular deals with component styles (component style belongs only to component template), so the old AngularJS will stay with version 3, but all Angular 7 components will use version 4.

I tried to `@import` Bootstrap 4 into `src/styles.css`, but the styles were applied to the whole project.

P.S. I am using `ngUpgrade` approach.

Comment: I'm affarid not since 2 version have different kind of code

Comment: Just spitballing here because I don't know how `@import` behave in this case but you could try importing  bootstrap4 inside the component.css files. Be sure that the css is loaded as `scoped` for the component only. There will probably more custom config to be implemented on the decorator side of the component as well.